# SQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Доброе утро.
Помогите решить задачку, нужно составить запрос. Названия базы и полей произвольные.
Sort all users by Last Login and select just activated users (ENABLED = true);

Comment: @Ruslan1987, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Хоть бы перевел для преличия

Comment: Перевод: отсортировать всех юзеров по Last Login и выбрать только активированных юзеров (ENABLED = true) (как-то так)

Comment: SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE LAST_LOGIN>'2015-02-18 00:00:01 ' ; SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE enabled='1' Я не могу понять как выбрать юзеров которые логинились в последний раз, и как обьеденить это все в один запрос. Нужно использовать подзапрос? или в конце указать .... WHERE LAST_LOGIN=??? AND enabled='1'? Буду очень признателен мастером sql.

Comment: SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE LAST_LOGIN>'2015-02-18 00:00:01 ' AND enabled='1';

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но примерно так:

```
SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `enabled` = 1 ORDER BY `last_login`
```

В конце добавить DESC для сортировки по убыванию.